# capistrano excute Makefile fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, makefile, capistrano

I have a problem with excute Makefile

deploy.rb:

```
namespace :deploy do
  after :deploy, :build_app do
    on roles(:app), in: :groups do
      execute "make production"
    end
  end
end
```

Makefile:

```
production:
    echo "make file production"
staging:
    echo "make file staging"
all:
    echo "make file all"
```

error when run "cap production deploy"

```
DEBUG [1f0a117d] Command: make production
DEBUG [1f0a117d]    make: *** No rule to make target `production'.  Stop.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as make production exit status: 2
make production stdout: make: *** No rule to make target `production'.  Stop.
make production stderr: Nothing written
```

Debug run direct on server "make production" => echo "make file production"

And if excute with only "make" it will running to the first tag

**--- Makefile addition**

```
production:
    npm install
    npm run deploy-production
    sudo docker rmi dashboard:latest; sudo echo 0
    sudo docker build -t dashboard:$(VERSION) .
    sudo docker tag -f dashboard:$(VERSION) dashboard:latest

staging:
    npm install
    npm run deploy-staging
    sudo docker rmi dashboard:latest; sudo echo 0
    sudo docker build -t dashboard:$(VERSION) .
    sudo docker tag -f dashboard:$(VERSION) dashboard:latest
```

Comment: is there a reason you run it via make instead of a simple `cap production deploy` ?

Comment: Yes. I need run it to build some code (npm, docker image, ...). For read easily, I remove all code not relate to bug

Comment: could you post the Makefile source? (ignore this just saw you did it)

Comment: @microspino Makefile added

Comment: is there anyway to get ENV in Makefile. I want run like this: npm run deploy-$(ENV)   :D

Comment: Haven't dug into it too much but it seems cap doesn't find your Makefile. I don't know about your linked_dirs and linked_files [see here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/)  that are set in your *deploy.rb*. Please have a look also at [hooks](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/before-after/#) and try issuing the same commands via [cap console](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/console/)

Comment: I make sure that Makefile load correctly. because when edit deploy.rb => excute "make" . It running the first one (echo production). Thanks @microspino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax for make env:

```
namespace :deploy do
  after :deploy, :build_app do
    on roles(:app), in: :groups do
      execute 'make','production'
    end
  end
end
```